# Upon opening my notebook, I must evaluate cell for code to work properly

Tags: manipulate, syntax

I am new to Mathematica.  Once I evaluate the cell containing the code, my Manipulate works as desired; however, if I open the file and do not evaluate the cell, the Manipulate goes haywire.  Can anyone help please?  The code below is all in the same cell.

```
Sequence1[n_] := { 1 / n, (-1)^n / n, 1 / Sqrt[n] };
Function1[x_] := { ( x - 2 )^2, 2 - x^2, 2^x };

Manipulate[

 Grid[ { { "Function" , "Sequence of Outputs" },

    { data = 
     List[Transpose[{Table[ Sequence1[n][[sss]], {n, 1, t}], 
        Table[ Function1[Sequence1[n][[sss]]][[hhh]], {n, 1, t}]}]]; 
    ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 5}}, 
     AspectRatio -> 1/1, ImageSize -> Full], 

    ListPlot[Table[Function1[Sequence1[n][[sss]]][[hhh]], {n, 1, t}], 
     PlotRange -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Full]},

   { "Close-Up" , "Tabular Values" }, 

   { data = 
     List[Transpose[{Table[ Sequence1[n][[sss]], {n, 1, t}], 
        Table[ Function1[Sequence1[n][[sss]]][[hhh]], {n, 1, t}]}]]; 
    ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-.1, .1}, {0, 5}}, 
     AspectRatio -> 1/1, ImageSize -> Full]  ,
     If[ t < 11, 
     TableForm[ 
      Transpose[ {Range[1, t], 
        Table[ Sequence1[n][[sss]], {n, 1, t} ], 
        Table[Function1[Sequence1[n][[sss]]][[hhh]], {n, 1, t}]}]], 
     TableForm[
      Transpose[ {Range[t - 10, t], 
        Table[Sequence1[n][[sss]], {n, t - 10, t} ], 
        Table[Function1[Sequence1[n][[sss]]][[hhh]], {n, t - 10, 
          t}]}]]]}},

  ItemSize -> {{Scaled[.4], Scaled[.4]}}, Frame -> All, 
  Spacings -> {2, 2}],

 {{sss, 3, "sequence"}, {1 -> " 1 / n ", 2 -> " (-1)^n / n ", 
   3 -> "1 / Sqrt[n] "}, 
  SetterBar}, {{hhh, 3, "f(x)="}, {1 -> "(x-2)^2", 2 -> "2-x^2", 
   3 -> "2^x"}, SetterBar}, {t, 1, 100, 1}]
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Which code are you talking about: the two functions `Function1` and `Sequence1`, or the code for the `Manipulate`?

Comment: You could try using the option `SaveDefinitions -> True` in the `Manipulate`.

Comment: This worked thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Add the `Initialization` option to your `Manipulate` as shown below:

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{"Function", 
    "Sequence of Outputs"}, {data = 
     List[Transpose[{Table[Sequence1[n][[sss]], {n, 1, t}], 
        Table[Function1[Sequence1[n][[sss]]][[hhh]], {n, 1, t}]}]];
    ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 5}}, AspectRatio -> 1/1,
      ImageSize -> Full], 
    ListPlot[Table[Function1[Sequence1[n][[sss]]][[hhh]], {n, 1, t}], 
     PlotRange -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Full]}, {"Close-Up", 
    "Tabular Values"}, {data = 
     List[Transpose[{Table[Sequence1[n][[sss]], {n, 1, t}], 
        Table[Function1[Sequence1[n][[sss]]][[hhh]], {n, 1, t}]}]];
    ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-.1, .1}, {0, 5}}, 
     AspectRatio -> 1/1, ImageSize -> Full], 
    If[t < 11, 
     TableForm[
      Transpose[{Range[1, t], Table[Sequence1[n][[sss]], {n, 1, t}], 
        Table[Function1[Sequence1[n][[sss]]][[hhh]], {n, 1, t}]}]], 
     TableForm[
      Transpose[{Range[t - 10, t], 
        Table[Sequence1[n][[sss]], {n, t - 10, t}], 
        Table[Function1[Sequence1[n][[sss]]][[hhh]], {n, t - 10, 
          t}]}]]]}}, ItemSize -> {{Scaled[.4], Scaled[.4]}}, 
  Frame -> All, 
  Spacings -> {2, 2}], {{sss, 3, "sequence"}, {1 -> " 1 / n ", 
   2 -> " (-1)^n / n ", 3 -> "1 / Sqrt[n] "}, 
  SetterBar}, {{hhh, 3, "f(x)="}, {1 -> "(x-2)^2", 2 -> "2-x^2", 
   3 -> "2^x"}, SetterBar}, {t, 1, 100, 1}, 
 Initialization :> (Sequence1[n_] := {1/n, (-1)^n/n, 1/Sqrt[n]};
   Function1[x_] := {(x - 2)^2, 2 - x^2, 2^x})]
```

Comment: This also worked, Thanks!  What is the difference between putting the initialization inside the manipulate vs the savedefinitions->true?

Comment: I spoke too soon.  Only the initialization code worked.  Thanks kalewallace.  I was experimenting in the same file, so the savedef code suggestion worked since the initialization code worked which I ran first.

Comment: The `SaveDefinitions` option "remembers" the value of the variable or the function before the notebook is closed, saving it within the notebook to where it is available when the notebook is reopened (even after the kernel is stopped). The `Initialization` option re-evaluates the expression whenever the Dynamic expression is displayed.  This is useful if your `Manipulate` involves large amounts of data, such as importing data or SQL servers. Both ways work fine for small functions like in your case.