# How can I make CDF which uses user defined function

Tags: cdf-format

I have a user defined function which is called many times in the code. I want to ask that when I am deploying the code to`CDF`, I need to define that user defined function also. I tried it using `DynamicModule` and `With`. But none is working. How should I give that user defined function so that it can be deployed into `CDF`.

Comment: Check out the `Initialization` option. See this QA: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9476/upon-opening-file-in-mathematica-i-must-evaluate-cell-for-code-to-work-properly/9493#9493.

Comment: No,I am calling the function and appending it to get the list.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a small example. I saved it to CDF and it works as is in the CDF. It has small functions in the `Initialization` section that are used by the Dynamics inside the `DynamicModule` to run the simple simulation to illustrate the idea.

Notice that this is not much different from putting all your functions in the `Initialization` section of the `Manipulate`, since `Manipulate` is basically a `DynamicModule`. So same idea.

```
DynamicModule[{sol, angle, bob, r, time = 0, animationRate = 1, y},

 Dynamic@Grid[{{Trigger[Dynamic[time], {0, Infinity, 0.01}, 
      animationRate,
      AppearanceElements -> {"PlayPauseButton", "ResetButton"}],
     Style["time (sec)", 10], Dynamic[time]},
    {Dynamic@
      Show[Graphics[{{Dashed, Gray, Thin, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}, {Red, 
          Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, bob}]},
         {Blue, PointSize[0.1], Point[bob]}},
        ImagePadding -> 10], ImageSize -> 300], SpanFromLeft}
    }, Frame -> True, Alignment -> Left],

 Initialization :> (
   sol := 
    First@NDSolve[{y''[t] + 0.1 y'[t] + Sin[y[t]] == 1.5 Cos[t], 
       y[0] == Pi/4, y'[0] == 0}, y, {t, time, time + 1}, 
      Sequence@ndsolveOptions];
   bob := {Sin[(y /. sol)[time]], -Cos[(y /. sol)[time]]};

   ndsolveOptions = {MaxSteps -> Infinity,
     Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
       Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}},
     AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10}
   )]
```

[image]